# Does anybody recognize this superhero t-shirt description?

Tags: marvel, comics, object-identification, clothing

I was in Dollar Tree the other day and passed a woman in a (formerly-) Marvel Comics tee which actually impressed me. Unfortunately, I neglected to immediately ask its origins and when I did come back to catch up with her, she was getting in her car and driving off.

It's a white tee with characters and paraphernalia or emblems in a 3×3 array. From what I could see on it, a head-shot of Vision was top center, what looked to be the Eye of Agammoto in the top right, and Mjolnir in the center or maybe center-right position.

I'll head back to check the Ross and Bealls Outlet that are in that same shopping center, but if you know where to find it IRL or have a link to it, please let me know.

"Excelsior!"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you provide a picture of the shirt?

Comment: Haha! No, afraid not. I wasn't taking photos of unknown women in dollar stores and if I had a retail image, I'd just run it thru TinEye.com.

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Marvel-Comics-Super-heroes-Logos-Mens-White-Tee-Shirt-/173720797419 ?

Comment: Yahtzee! Innumerable thanks, @Bitterfiction! Wow, and Ant-Man! ... Wonder Man. :| Two Spidey images, but he's practically their cornerstone, tho they could've included the FF. I can't immediately ID the bottom led

Comment: ... bottom left, but it's even better than thought. Hopefully it's available elsewhere than eBay. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh! Capt. Britain's sceptre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the shirt in question:

[image]

It is available at eBay, and possibly other locations:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/Marvel-Comics-Super-heroes-Logos-Mens-White-Tee-Shirt-/173720797419

Comment: Must. Have. T-shirt.

Comment: It turns out that the spider is for Black Widow., My bad. And I've been wondering (pardon pun) that the W may be The Wasp, tho I can't recall her in blue and red, but she's had a lot of costumes.